# What will be committed?

Tags: svn, commit

For the first time I had to commit something in SVN from the command line and I realized that I actually don't know, what would get committed. So far I've been using TortoiseSVN so that was easy. And by "will get committed" I mean when I use `svn commit` without specifying files explicitly.

My first guess was `svn status` but this shows me a lot of files, including ignored ones and others so not all of them will be committed.

Then there's `svn diff` which probably does what I need but is way too verbose.

So I guess what I'm looking for is `svn status -q`?

1. Does `svn status -q` list **ALL** and **ONLY** files which will get committed?
2. Does `svn diff` list **exactly** the same files, just with all the changes in them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well `svn status -q` prints only essential information while performing an operation. That is, if there are new files in your project that you didn't yet add to the svn repo, `svn status -q` will not print those files and you 
can end up by forgetting to do `svn add` on those files.

`svn diff` will display local modification in a working copy.

Regarding This, the answer to both of your questions are yes and yes